# Is there any advantage of joining on an indexed and non-indexed columns at the same time?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, indexing

If i have a join on a non-indexed column, will adding another criteria in the join on an indexed column help?

For eg - Two tables Table1 and Table2 exist. the column tran_date is indexed, but tran_id is not. Will the second code run faster than the first? If so, how does SQL exactly operate on such joins? Table1 is unique on tran_id, while table2 is unique at tran_id - sku level.
Also, tran_id is a varchar(50) type of column

```
SELECT a.tran_id, a.tran_date, b.sku
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on a.tran_id = b.tran_id;
```

vs

```
SELECT a.tran_id, a.tran_date, b.sku
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on a.tran_id = b.tran_id and a.tran_date = b.tran_date;
```

I'm using Oracle environment

Comment: You are likely to solicit much better answers for this question on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), this question may even have already been answered there.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the explain plan for the queries and get an idea what is happening.

In my rough opinion the second query should run faster, because the second query will evaluate the a.tran_date = b.tran_date condition way faster,and then use the filtered rows(which may be really few in number)to evaluate the condition a.tran_id = b.tran_id.
Thus, the second query has to do much less work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated question, and there is no single answer for a sophisticated database such as Oracle.  Oracle can choose among several different methods for doing joins.  And which method it chooses depends on statistics gathered about the table.

As a general rule, you can think that including the column with the index will improve performance; just be prepared to find situations where this intuition might be wrong.  But, if the relationship on transaction ids is 1-0/1 (at most one match) and Oracle implements a hash join algorithm, then that will perform pretty well.

Worse, if Oracle implemented a hybrid join, first using the index for the date and then doing filtering for the id, things could get bad if there are multiple date matches causing the data to multiply.

If you want to learn more about how Oracle does joins, you can start by looking at the documentation for the [optimizer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#PFGRF001).